# CSS animation on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a website and I have css animations for dropdowns but I want them to show up on click instead of on hover on the sub menu and cant seem to figure it out 
here is the code I am currently working with Sorry about all the PHP mixed in I copied it straight from the source. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwrNaZ

```
  $( "#horiz-menu ul li > ul" ).click(function()
```

I Dont know jQuery very well but this is what I have so far.

Comment: Start by changing the styles that target 'hover' states to target a particular class instead, then use jQuery to toggle this class. If you need help more specifically, you'll have to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I don't know very much jQuery but what i need is for the submenu to appear on click vs hover but i want all other dropdowns appear on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using JQuery:

JQuery

```
$( "#horiz-menu a" ).click(function(e){
   $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
#horiz-menu ul.active {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

Heres a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/hw9fsLb2/1/

Comment: The only problem with this is they still appear when hovered over.

Comment: Remove the `:hover` from your CSS and they wont.  Use jQuery to toggle a different class for animations.

Comment: If i remove the hover then the main drop down wont work.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem I am having with this is links arent working anymore

Comment: Remove the `e.preventDefault();` and try again.  `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action on the target element in an event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#horiz-menu ul li > ul" ).click(function(){
$( "#horiz-menu li" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```